# System.AccessViolationException in Asp.net with leadtools imaging api

Tags: asp.net, leadtools-sdk

I am getting a weird error in asp.net while using leadtools imaging api. Here's the stack trace.

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at SetThreadData(_THREADDATA* )
   at Leadtools.Codecs.CodecsOptions.Use()
   at Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.DoSave(SaveParams saveParams)
   at Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Save(RasterImage image, Stream stream, RasterImageFormat format, Int32 bitsPerPixel)
   at BarCodeHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctxt)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue with a tiff file, but I found a solution. When the image i am trying to load very tall and wide they have to be reduced and then they'll work fine.